# How to find whether the sum of a geometric series is prime or divisible by 3, 13 or 125?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $A = 1+5+5^2+\dots+5^{99}$, then $A$ is:

1. A prime number
2. not divisible by 3
3. divisible by 13
4. divisible by 125

I know this is a sum of a Geometric Progression, so $ A = (5^{100}-1)/4$ but I cannot find $5^{100}$ So I thought of finding a pattern between the progression starting from 1. I get 1,6,31,131,... but cannot seem to be finding any pattern. May someone Help?

Comment: $5^{100}=25^{50}=(-1)^{50}=1$ modulo $13$.

Comment: what is modulo?

Comment: Do you really mean $1+5^2+\dots$, or is it $1+5+5^2+\cdots$? If it is the latter, you can deal with the choices easily.

Comment: $$5\equiv-1\pmod3\implies5^{100}\equiv(-1)^{100}$$

So, $3|(5^{100}-1)$

As $(3,4)=1,3$ will divide $\dfrac{5^{100}-1}{5-1}$

Comment: what is meaning of congruency sign and mod can you explain it without using them or perhaps provide a link where they are explained.

Comment: @RaghavSingal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: @RaghavSingal: just read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: Yeah.. do $5^{100}=25^{50} = (2*13 - 1)^{50} = 2^{50}13^{50} - 50*2^{49}13^{49} + ......  + {50 \choose 2}*2^2*13^2 - 50*2*13 + 1$.  So $5^{100} - 1 = 2^{50}13^{50} - 50*2^{49}13^{49} + ......  + {50 \choose 2}*2^2*13^2 - 50*2*13$ which is divisible by 13.  Learn modulo arithmatic.  It's the arithmetic of remainders.  That way you don't have to deal with all that $2^{50}13^{50} - 50*2^{49}13^{49} + ......  + {50 \choose 2}*2^2*13^2 - 50*2*13$ shit.  You can get right to the important stuff $5^{100} \equiv 1 \mod 13$ which means $5^{100}$ divided by $13$ has remainder $1$.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for providing an alternative which I can understand it helped! Also, I will definitely study modulo arithmetic.

Comment: You are welcome.  Modulo arithmetic is fairly intuitive at first (if a is 1 more than a perfect multiple of 7 and b is 2 more than a perfect multiple of 7 then a+b; a*b; (a+b)^3 will be 1+2, 1*2; (1+2)^3 etc more than a perfect multiples of 7) but it becomes a *great* tool for solving systems of equations.  (what are the last 4 digits of $2037^{13452}$?  Surprisingly that's *easy* to solve!)  However comments like "Oh, just learn a new branch of math you've never heard of" are ... off-putting.

Comment: Point is... with $5^2 = 2*13 - 1$ we are only interested in what happens to the "remainder" -1.  The (2*13) no matter how manipulated (and with the binomial theory it gets *very* manipulated) it's always a multiple of 13 and we still only care about the remainder.  Modulo arithmetic allows us a vocabular to talk about only the remainders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that you mean $1+5+5^2+\cdots +5^{99}$. Let's deal with the choices one at a time.

Of course 4.) is false, all the terms except one are multiples of $5$. So the sum cannot be a multiple of $5$.

1.) is clearly false, we have an even number of odd numbers. The sum is therefore even, and thus not prime.

2.) Group in groups of $2$. Note that $1+5$ is a multiple of $3$, and so is $5^2+5^3$, which is $5^2(1+5)$. The same is true of $5^4+5^5=5^4(1+5)$, and so on. So our whole sum is a multiple of $3$.

3.) Note that $1+5+5^2+5^3$ is a multiple of $13$, and therefore so is $5^4+5^5+5^6+5^7$ and so on. (We are grouping in groups of $4$.)

Comment: Who naturally spots that $1+5+5^2+5^3$ is a multiple of 13? I have to assume the author of the problem had modular arithmetic in mind.

Comment: The author did.  But he rose to the challenge to come up with an answer for the OP which didn't use it.

Comment: Not too hard to note $1 + 5 + 5^2 + 5^3 = (1 + 5^2) + 5(1+5^2) = 26*6$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: From a comment, it looks as if OP may not be familiar with modular arithmetic.

Comment: @fleablood: yes, duh, it is not hard to check but not something one would go looking for. I don't see how that method will help the OP solve other problems.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I certainly agree that it is important that OP become familiar with modular arithmetic, and your answer will help to motivate that.

Comment: It'd be useful and easy for the OP to learn i) $a \equiv b \mod c$ means $a - b$ is divisible by $c$.  ii) if $a \equiv b \mod c$ then $na \equiv nb \mod c$ (because $na - nb$ is divisible by $c$.  And iii) if $a \equiv b \mod c$ then $a^k = b^k \mod c$.  Knowing that $25^{50}\equiv (-1)^50 \equiv 1 \mod 13 \implies $5^{100} - 1 $ is divisible by 13 will be easy to grasp.  Once the OP gets used to it.

Comment: Mmmm.  modular arithmetic is easier but ... I think recognizing 1+a + a^2 +...  will have such mini factors can be useful.

Comment: I'm always amazed how you manage to solve all these problems in no time !

Comment: Thank you for providing a simple solution! It has made the problem very easy! It helped!

Comment: @RaghavSingal: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question concerns divisibility, consider reducing modulo $3$, $13$, etc.

In particular, note

$$5^{100}\equiv(-1)^{100}\equiv 1 \mod 3$$

and

$$5^{100}\equiv 25^{50}\equiv (-1)^{50}\equiv 1\mod 13$$

What does this tell you about the divisibility of $\frac{1}{4}(5^{100}-1)$ by $3$ and $13$?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: ...because the OP stated in the comments s/he doesn't know modulo arithmetic?

Comment: @fleablood: I posted this before the OP said so. There is nothing in the problem statement that says not to use modular arithmetic or gives any context about the examination in which the problem appeared.

Comment: I know.  I don't know why the downvotes.  I wouldn't and didn't downvote it.  I think it's a good answer.

Comment: @fleablood The answer can be useful to anyone in the future, not just OP.